# Create Circle Google Apps Script fails

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-plus

Trying to create a circle for a user in my domain, I'm super admin, i can create the circle for my self, but not for another user in the domain, i get "Forbidden". I have enabled the API's as in the [instructions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced), what can i do?
Printscreen on my script here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Na649.png

I have added all the API's needed, I am superadmin.

```
function createCircle() {
  var userId = "103105680958218578664";
  var circle = PlusDomains.newCircle();
  circle.displayName = 'Tech support';

  circle = PlusDomains.Circles.insert(circle, userId);
  Logger.log('Created "Tech support" circle with id: ' + circle.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this out yet, but I'm wondering if this is an authorization issue. Even as an app admin, you're not allowed to do things on behalf of a user.

https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/circles/insert indicates that circle.insert may only be done for "the authorized user".

I'm wondering if you need to use the domain-wide delegation for authentication as specified at https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/delegation

Answer (score 0):

> This service **doesn't support the domain-wide delegation feature** in the underlying API. This means that domain admininstrators are not able to run a script on behalf of users in their domain.

Source: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/plus-domains